# Coding for two different clustering methods

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I used two different clustering methods to generate two clustering results and each cluster method contains 10 different groups. However, they are coded differently. The below example shows the clustering results:

```
set.seed(1)

Df <- data.frame(Var1 = sample(1:6, 100, replace =T), Var2 = sample(1:6,100, replace =T))

table(Df)
```

I want to find the percentage agreement(or number of agreement) between these two methods and recode Cluster2 to levels of Cluster1 so that they will have the maximum percentage agreement (or number of cases). I wrote some algorithm to do it but was not very successful after the number of clusters increase. My dataset has over 100000 cases.

Comment: table(Df)/nrow(Df)

Comment: My goal is to maximize percentage agreement by assigning A,B,C to Cluster 2, so 1, 2,3 in cluster 2 will become A,B,C as well. In this case, 3 will be B, 1 becomes A, and 3 becomes C. I can use table(Df) to find the maximum matched membership but sometime thing gets complicated with multiple matches.

Comment: Df$Var2 <- Df$Var1 ... lol now you have 100% agreement! In all seriousness though, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it, I think I found an easy answer to my question. I can simply use a loop to trim it down and find the matches.

```
set.seed (1)
df <- data.frame(Cluster1 = sample(LETTERS[1:n], c, replace =T), Cluster2 = sample(1:n,c, replace =T))
findmatch <- function(df, group1 = "Cluster1", group2 = "Cluster2" ) {
    n <- length(unique(df[, group1]))
    matches <- matrix(NA, n, 2) 
    for(i in 1:n) {
        if(i==1) {
        table1 <- table(df[, group1], df[,group2])
        } else if(i<n) {
        table1 <- table1[-maxs[1],-maxs[2]]  
       } 
       maxs <- which(table1 == max(table1), arr.ind = TRUE)
       if(i < n) {
       matches[i,1:2] <- c(rownames(table1)[maxs[1]], colnames(table1)[maxs[2]])    
       } else {
         matches[i,1:2] <- c(rownames(table1)[-maxs[1]], colnames(table1)[-maxs[2]])    
     }
   }
   return(matches)
 }
findmatch(df=df)


      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "J"  "5" 
 [2,] "I"  "7" 
 [3,] "A"  "6" 
 [4,] "E"  "3" 
 [5,] "D"  "10"
 [6,] "C"  "8" 
 [7,] "B"  "1" 
 [8,] "F"  "9" 
 [9,] "H"  "2" 
[10,] "G"  "4"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a shotgun approach, since I do not know how many clusters there are in the real data. I try here all possible combinations:

```
df <- data.frame(Cluster1 = c("A","A", "B", "B", "C","C", "C"), 
                 Cluster2 = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "2","1","3"))

require(gtools)
comb <- permutations(n = 3, r = 3, v = 1:3)

#try every combination and count the matches
nmatch <- apply(comb,1,function(x) sum(LETTERS[match(df$Cluster2,x)] == df$Cluster1))

#pick the best performing translation
best <- comb[which.max(nmatch),]
# generate translation table
data.frame(Cluster2 = 1:3, Cluster2new = LETTERS[best])
```

result:

```
  Cluster2 Cluster2new
1        1           A
2        2           C
3        3           B
```

your new example data:

```
set.seed(314)
df <- data.frame(Cluster1 = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, replace =T), Cluster2 = sample(1:6,100, replace =T))

require(gtools)
comb <- permutations(n = 6, r = 6, v = 1:6)

#try every combination and count the matches
nmatch <- apply(comb,1,function(x) sum(LETTERS[match(df$Cluster2,x)] == df$Cluster1))

#pick the best performing translation
best <- comb[which.max(nmatch),]
# generate translation table
data.frame(Cluster2 = 1:3, Cluster2new = LETTERS[best])
```

result:

```
  Cluster2 Cluster2new
1        1           B
2        2           D
3        3           C
4        1           A
5        2           E
6        3           F
```

---

calculating the permutations seems to be the limiting factor. Therefor I have an alternate solution, that randomly samples for posibilities, and calculates the matching percentage. This method is a lot faster, but will probably not include the very best solution to the problem.

```
set.seed(314)

c = 10000
n = 10
tries = 1000

df <- data.frame(Cluster1 = sample(LETTERS[1:n], c, replace =T), Cluster2 = sample(1:n,c, replace =T))

#try every combination and count the matches
nmatch <- sapply(1:tries,function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  comb <- sample(1:n,n)
  sum(LETTERS[match(df$Cluster2,comb)] == df$Cluster1)
  })

#pick the best performing translation
best <- which.max(nmatch)
# generate translation table
set.seed(best)
data.frame(Cluster2 = 1:n, Cluster2new = LETTERS[sample(1:n,n)])

nmatch[best]/c
```

result:

```
   Cluster2 Cluster2new
1         1           B
2         2           J
3         3           D
4         4           C
5         5           A
6         6           G
7         7           E
8         8           F
9         9           I
10       10           H
> 
  > nmatch[best]/c
[1] 0.1099
```

---

or a slower iterative proces:

```
solve <- function(start)
{
  sol <- integer()
  start <- sample(1:n)
  left <- start
  for(i in start){

    nmatch <- sapply(left, function(x) {
      cl <- df[df$Cluster2==x,]
      sum(LETTERS[cl$Cluster2] == cl$Cluster1)
    })
    ix <- which.max(nmatch)
    sol[i] <- left[ix]
    left <- left[-ix]
  }
  sol
}

nmatch <- sapply(1:tries, function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  sum(LETTERS[match(df$Cluster2,solve(sample(1:n)))] == df$Cluster1)
})

best <- which.max(nmatch)

data.frame(Cluster2 = 1:n, Cluster2new = LETTERS[sample(1:n,n)])

nmatch[best]/c
```

results:

```
   Cluster2 Cluster2new
1         1           D
2         2           G
3         3           C
4         4           I
5         5           E
6         6           A
7         7           B
8         8           J
9         9           F
10       10           H
>     
  >     nmatch[best]/c
[1] 0.1121
```

As an illustration, the second random proces, might be better in getting a good solution, when you look at the distribution of `nmatch` per method:

[image]

Comment: This method is promising and good for small numbers of clusters. My problem is that I have 15 clusters in each of the two cluster methods, the computation time is too great!

Comment: I added another approach, to try make it faster but less accurate.

Comment: And another method. Wonder if someone with a more mathematical background than me has a better solution to this problem?